# Which statistical test to use for customer buying subscription for A/B test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, ab-test

I'm running an A/B test, where control has default experience and the test variant has personalised experience. 
The users I am targeting randomly are lapsed users on a particular subscription and testing whether, if shown a personalised experience; the users will convert more.
Now, of all the columns in my data, I have two columns: **user_id** and **ARR** column(in $).
How can I test the w.r.t **ARR** column if my test is statistically significant or not?

Comment: Without any other context, and assuming randomisation is done appropriately, there is no selection bias, we have an adequate sample size, etc. perform a $t$-test between the two groups. I would also suggest using bootstrap to estimate the error around this estimate in a non-parametric way too.